# JBoss 6 Class Loading Issues

Tags: java, jboss

I am using JBoss 6 and i want to deploy my war application. I was deploying my application to JBoss5 successfully by using jboss-classloading.xml under my web-inf directory. This isolation method was working great but it doesnt seem to be working under JBoss 6. I am getting classloader errors all over the place. What should i do for the configuration?

Stack trace is here: http://sharetext.org/UYV

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be barking up the wrong tree but I've seen a similar problem in 4.2.x where the clasloader compliance was a problem (which affects the order classes are loaded).

We solved it by editing deploy/jboss-web.deployer/META-INF/jboss-service.xml
Change these two lines to **true**
`<attribute name="Java2ClassLoadingCompliance">false</attribute>

<attribute name="UseJBossWebLoader">false</attribute>`